# Understanding proof that $[X_e,Y_e]\in T_e G$ generates the right-invariant vector field $[X,Y]$ on $G$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $X_e,Y_e \in T_eG$ be vectors and $G = GL(n).$ Then the right translation is given by $Y_g = Y_e g$ and $X_g = X_e g.$

Now, I have a proof showing that $[X_e,Y_e] \in T_eG$ is the element generating the right- invariant vector field $[X,Y]$ on $G.$

Now, the proof starts with

$$([X,Y]_g)_{i,j}) = \sum_{k,l=1}^{N} \left((Y_g)_{k,l} \frac{\partial (X_g)_{i,j}}{\partial g_{k,l}}- (X_g)_{k,l}  \frac{\partial (Y_g)_{i,j}}{\partial g_{k,l}} \right),$$

but I don't understand where the derivatives come from in this expression. Can anybody explain this equality to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ingredients here:

(1) The Lie bracket is actually the Lie derivative $\mathscr L_X Y$ of the vector fields. By definition, this is
$$\mathscr L_X Y(p) = \frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0} \phi_{-t*}Y_{\phi_t(p)},$$
where $\phi_t$ is the flow of $X$.

(2) The flow of the *right*-invariant vector field $X$ is given by *left* multiplication by $\exp(tX_e)$. (Solve $\dfrac{dg}{dt}=X_eg$.)

Putting these together, we have 
\begin{align*}
\mathscr L_X Y(p) &=\frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0} \phi_{-t*}Y_{\phi_t(p)} \\
&= \frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0} \exp(-tX_e)Y_e\exp(tX_e) = -X_eY_e+Y_eX_e,
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: Hello, I noticed that this question and especially your answer is related to my current question. Maybe you could have a look at my question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1399298/lie-bracket-confusing-proof-from-lecture . Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This is really the definition of Lie bracket (defined on $GL(n)$ as a manifold). The definition is

$$\begin{split}
[X, Y]_g &= XY - YX\\
& = \sum_{k,l} X_{k,l}\partial_{g_{k,l}} \ Y - Y_{k,l} \partial_{g_{k,l}} \ X
\end{split}$$

That's why you have to differentiate the vector fields. (For some reason I don't know why, it's of by a sign)

Comment: The definition you gave for Lie bracket is for left-invariant vector fields. For right-invariant, the sign changes. Why?

Comment: @TedShifrin : I haven't dealt with the group structure yet. $X$, $Y$ are arbitrary vector fields.

Comment: So are you suggesting that for right invariant vector fields, one needs to add a -ve sign to the definition?

Comment: I'm saying that with the definition of Lie derivative, with right-invariant vector fields you get the negative of the usual Lie bracket definition.

Comment: @TedShifrin could you explain to me why this happens? Cause I think I did not understand the sign change.

Comment: I will sketch this in a separate answer.